# Create new row for each value that is in an array html javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this array:

```
var output = [[[a], [a1, a3, a5]], [[b], [b1, b2, b3]]]
```

and i wish to create a table as per below in html with javascript:

```
a  |  b
-------
a1 | b1
a3 | b2
a5 | b3
```

but at the moment I'm only getting it like this:

```
   a     |    b
--------------------
a1,a3,a5 | b1,b2,b3
```

with this code

```
  var table = '<table ' + TABLEFORMAT + ' ">';

  for (var row = 0; row < output.length; row++) {

    table += '<tr>';

    for (var col = 0; col < output[row].length; col++) {
      if (output[row][col] === "" || 0) {
        table += '<td>' + '' + '</td>';
      } else
        if (row === 0) {
          table += '<th>' + output[col][row] + '</th>';
        } else {
         table += '<td>' + output[col][row] + '</td>';
        }
    }
    table += '</tr>';
  }
```

is it possible to do so?

Comment: @decpk answered it, but as a suggestion, you might want to restructure your array into something like `output = {a: [a1, a2, a3], b: [b1, b2, b3]}` for a more friendly structure to work with and iterate over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could transform the data to a table like structure and then create the table.

```js
const
    pad = (array, tag) => array.map(v => `<${tag}>${v}</${tag}>`).join(''),
    raw = [[['a'], ['a1', 'a3', 'a5']], [['b'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']]],
    data = raw.reduce((r, [[h], a]) => {
        r.header.push(h);
        a.forEach((v, i) => (r.body[i] = r.body[i] || []).push(v));
        return r;
    }, { header: [], body: [] }),
    table = document.createElement('table');

table.innerHTML = `<table>
    <thead><tr>${pad(data.header, 'th')}</tr></thead>
    <tbody>${pad(data.body.map(a => pad(a, 'td')), 'tr')}
</tbody>`;

document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: the above works great! but unfortunately google app script doesn't recognise/getting error at ??= :(

Comment: please try without [nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

Comment: works great! thanks so much for saving me hours on figuring this out. i appreciate it very much

Comment: also out of curiosity, can we add empty col in this code?

Comment: you could take a space or `&nbsp;` in `raw`.

Comment: seems like if the number of rows for each col is not the same as the others, it will push? the row to the wrong col. it's alright. above is already good. will figure out this part without having to alter the raw data

Comment: you need at last an indicator of empty cell. otherwise you could replace `push` with a direct assignment to an index.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace forEach with for..loop if you're not comfortable with forEach.

```js
var table = '<table>';

var output = [
  [
    ["a"],
    ["a1", "a3", "a5"]
  ],
  [
    ["b"],
    ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
  ]
]

output[0].forEach((arr, i, src) => {
  const nextArr = output[1];
  if (i === 0) {
    table += `<tr>`
    table += `<th>${arr[i]} ${nextArr[i]}</th>`
    table += `</tr>`
  } else {
    arr.forEach((el, index, nestedSrc) => {
      table += `<tr>`
      table += `<td>${el} ${nextArr[i][index]}</td>`
      table += `</tr>`
    })
  }
})
table += `</table>`;

document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = table;
```

Comment: thanks! will try it out. Can ask will this work if we have more array values i.e [[[a], [a1,a2,a3]], [[b], [b1 b2,b3]], [[c], [c1,c2,c3]]]  or just those two?

Comment: just for 2 steps only

Comment: is there a way to make it dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

The second level array you need to loop and display in a separate table.

```js
function test() {
var output = [[['a'], ['a1', 'a3', 'a5']], [['b'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']]];
var table = '<table>';

  for (var row = 0; row < output.length; row++) {

    table += '<tr>';

    for (var col = 0; col < output[row].length; col++) {
      if (output[row][col] === "" || 0) {
        table += '<td>' + '' + '</td>';
      } else
        if (row === 0) {
          table += '<th>' + output[col][row] + '</th>';
        } else {
        tmpArr = output[col][row];
        var tmp = '<table>';
        for(i=0; i<tmpArr.length;i++) {
          tmp +='<tr><td>' + tmpArr[i] + '</td></tr>';
        }
        tmp += '</table>';
         table += '<td>' + tmp + '</td>';
        }
    }
    table += '</tr>';
  }
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = table;
}
test();
```

```html
<div id="output">

</div>
```

Comment: thanks suresh. does this work if there's another col as well? i.e i.e [[[a], [a1,a2,a3]], [[b], [b1 b2,b3]], [[c], [c1,c2,c3]]].

Answer (score 1):

HTML tables are row oriented so the outer loop is for the rows while the inner loop is for each cell within the rows. The way the array of arrays of arrays seems to be column oriented which if not considered an anti-pattern it is most certainly non-standard and excessively unnecessary and difficult.

The demo below generates a `<table>` with `<thead>` and `<th>` and content in the desired positions. The functions are reusable and accepts this pattern:

```
Array of Arrays of Arrays 
[[[tH], [tD, tD, tD]], [[tH], [tD, tD, tD]], [[tH], [tD, tD, tD]]]

Simplified Linear Array
[tH, tD, tD, tD, tH, tD, tD, tD, tH, tD, tD, tD]
```

For every `tH` add +1 to `colQty` and the `tD` must be the same amount for each column. So the above example should have `colQty=3`. Number of columns could be determined programmatically but that would be an entirely new question.

***Details are commented in example below***

```js
let insane = [
  [['a'], ['a1', 'a3', 'a5', 'a7', 'a9']], 
  [['b'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5']], 
  [['c'], ['c2', 'c4', 'c6', 'c8', 'c10']]
];

// Pass in an array of arrays of arrays and number of columns
function columnFlow(arrArrArr, colQty) {
  // Flatten that crazy array in order to avoid dealing with nested data
  const dataArray = arrArrArr.flat().flat();
  // Determine number of rows 
  const rowQty = dataArray.length / colQty;
  // Declare counters used in loops
  let r, c, i;
  
  // Create a HTML table
  const T = `<table><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>`;
  const hdr = `<th></th>`;
  const cel = `<td></td>`;
  addHTML(T);
  const table = document.querySelector('table');
  const tHead = table.querySelector('thead');
  const tBody = table.querySelector('tbody');
  
  // Add <tr>, <th>, and <td>
  for (r=0; r < rowQty; r++) {
    if (r === 0) {
      let hRow = tHead.insertRow();
      addHTML(hdr, colQty, hRow);
    } else {
      let dRow = tBody.insertRow();
      addHTML(cel, colQty, dRow);
    }
  }
  
  /*
  Define counter outside of loops in order to access dataArray linearly
  */
  i = 0;
  /*
  Content is inserted into each <th> and <td> by column
  */
  for (c=0; c < colQty; c++) {
    for (r=0; r < rowQty; r++) {
      let cell = table.rows[r].cells[c];
      cell.textContent = dataArray[i];
      i++;
    }
  }
};

/*
Pass a string representing HTML, number of times to be added, and the 
element to add it to. If second parameter is invalid or ignored, it 
defaults to 1. If the third parameter is skipped it defaults to <body>.
*/
function addHTML(string, quantity, node = document.body) {
  let qty = Number.isNaN(quantity) || !quantity ? 1 : quantity;
  for (let i=0; i < qty; i++) {
    node.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', string);
  }
};
  
columnFlow(insane, 3);
```

```css
table {
  display: inline-table;
  margin: 10px;
  font: 3ch/1 Consolas;
}

td {
  padding: 6px;
  border-top: 1px black solid;
  text-align: center;
}

th, td {
  border-right: 1px black solid;
}

th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: wow this is a very good explanation. i appreciate it very much. thank you